# Getting a Fragment from a DialogPreference?

Tags: android, fragment, dialog-preference

I have a DialogPreference, that I'm trying to get a Fragment that is added to it (Google Maps, if anyone cares). The fragment has an id tag in the XML code, and I'm setting the dialog via `setDialogLayoutResource()`. However, I'm struggling to get a reference to the fragment (So I can set some settings to it, and get data out from it). I need to get a reference to it before the user can start playing with the data.

What I've tried so far is this:

```
@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    ((Fragment) getDialog()
            .getOwnerActivity()
            .getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
}
```

This doesn't work because getDialog returns null at this point in the lifecycle. If there's a better way to reference the activity or FragmentManager, I'd love to see it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by casting the Context as an Activity.

```
((Activity) getContext()).getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
```